# Azure iothub with azure functions - Singleton per deviceId

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-iot-hub

I would like to have a long-running azure function per deviceId and hopefully using Azure functions as I want to minimise the infrastructure I have to manage.
Does anyone know whether this pattern is possible?

I have checked DurableFunctions but I don't think I could route all the messages with the same DeviceID to a function?

It would be ok if the function is rebooted every 5 minutes.

Of course, the alternative could be to use Service Fabric Reliable actors (potentially with service mesh once it becomes available) , but I would like to keep the solution as simple as possitve, hence why my focus on Functions.

Comment: "...I don't think I could route all the messages with the same DeviceID to a function?" Why? What's the problem?

Comment: As far as I know Azure functions EvenHub bindings doesn't support this, plus the fact that Functions are sort lived?

Comment: Not sort in Azure Function, you can sort using Azure IoT Hub route to a custom endpoint linked to an event hub.

Answer (score 0):

The question is - what is your concern, that you have to route messages with the same `DeviceID` to the(same?) function?

While out-of-the-box integration with IoT Hub(and by that I understand using inbuilt EH endpoint and Event Hub trigger) does not support this(as EH by design doesn not support things like filtering or topics), you have other options:

- you could filter each even directly in a function
- you could use Event Grid + additional function, which will just forward messages from IoT Hub to Event Grid and then you will let Event Grid route messages based on a specific parameter
- you could use Service Bus and topics feature

Could you elaborate a little bit on *long-running azure function per deviceId* so we possibly can meet your needs better?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all,
In my scenario I need to call an external service.this external service is a stateful service that will calculate the indoor position of each device. The external service is exposed over udp and I need to keep the connection open , one per device, hence why I wanted to have a long running function , to host the udp client.

It feels like service fabric actors (potentially with service mesh ) are the best options.

Thanks all !